# How to take care of this error: invalid conversion from 'bool (*)(int)' to 'int'?

Tags: c++, templates, methods, sortedlist

I'm writing this code for generic sorted list, and I have to write a filter method, without knowing what type of argument I will get. So I wrote it like that :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

#include "dummy.h"
using namespace std;

#ifndef SORT_H
#define SORT_H

template <class T>
class LinkedList {
    struct Node {
        Node(const T &in) : data(in) {}
        T data;
        Node * next;
    };

    class Iterator
    {
        Node *m_ptr;              // pointer to current node in the list
    public:
        Iterator(Node * node) {
            m_ptr = node;
        }
        Iterator& operator++() {
            m_ptr = m_ptr -> next();
            return *this;
        }
        Iterator operator++(int) {
            Iterator temp(*this);
            m_ptr = m_ptr -> next();
            return temp;
        }
        bool operator==(const Iterator other) const {
            return m_ptr==other.m_ptr; }
        bool operator!=(const Iterator other) const
        { return m_ptr!=other.m_ptr; }
        string& operator*()
        { return m_ptr->data(); }
        operator bool()
        { return m_ptr!=0; }
    };

    Node * head;

public:
    LinkedList() {
        head = nullptr;
    }
    LinkedList(T value) {
        head -> data = value;
        head -> next = nullptr;
    }

    ~LinkedList() {
        while(head != nullptr) {
            Node * n = head->next;
            delete head;
            head = n;
        }
    }
    void operator = (T &t) {
        head = t.head;
    }

//    LinkedList(LinkedList &list){
//        Node * tmp = list.head;
//        Node * curr = list.head -> next;
//        while (curr) {
//            tmp -> next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(tmp-> next));
//            tmp -> next = curr;
//            tmp = tmp -> next;
//            curr = curr -> next;
//        }
//    }

    int length() {
        int counter = 0;
        Node * tmp = head;
        while( tmp ) {
            counter++;
            tmp = tmp -> next;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    void insert(T value) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(head));
            head -> data = value;
            head -> next = nullptr;
            return;
        }
        Node* n = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(n));
        n -> data = value;

        Node* tmp = head;
        while (tmp != nullptr) {
           if (value > tmp -> data && tmp -> next != nullptr) {
               if (tmp -> next -> data > value) {
                   Node * curr = tmp -> next;
                   tmp -> next = n;
                   n -> next = curr;
                   return;
               } else {
                   tmp = tmp -> next;
               }
           } else if (value > tmp -> data && tmp -> next == nullptr) {
               tmp -> next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(tmp -> next));
               n -> next = nullptr;
               tmp -> next = n;
               return;
           } else if (value == tmp -> data && tmp -> next == NULL) {
               tmp -> next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(tmp -> next));
               n -> next = nullptr;
               tmp -> next = n;
               return;
           } else if (value == tmp -> data && tmp -> next != NULL) {
               n -> next = tmp -> next;
               tmp -> next = n;
               return;
           } else {
               n -> next = tmp;
               head = n;
               return;
           }
        }
    }

    void remove(T value) {
        Node* old = head -> next;
        free(head);
        head = old;
    }

    void print() {
        Node *curr = head;
        while (curr) {
            cout << curr->data << endl;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    Iterator begin() {
        return head->next();
    }
    Iterator end() {
        return 0;
    }
};


#endif
```

And my main looks like that :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sortedList.h"
#include "dummy.h"

bool func(int num) {
    if (num % 2 != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    Dummy teeth(24);
    teeth.add(7);
    Dummy slime(11);
    slime.add(1);
    Dummy josh(32);
    LinkedList<Dummy> teeth_list;
    teeth_list.insert(teeth);
    teeth_list.insert(slime);
    teeth_list.insert(josh);
    int num = teeth_list.length();
    cout << "The length is: " << num << endl;
    teeth_list.remove(slime);
    cout << "Now printing Dummy list" << endl;
    teeth_list.insert(slime);
    LinkedList<Dummy> new_int_list;
    new_int_list = teeth_list;
    teeth_list.print();
    cout << "Now printing new_int_list" << endl;
    new_int_list.print();

    LinkedList <Dummy> dummy1;
    dummy1 = dummy1.filter(teeth_list, &func);

//    LinkedList <Dummy> dummy(teeth_list);
//    cout << "Now printing new_dummy_list" << endl;
//    new_int_list.print();


    return 0;
}
```

The Dummy class looks like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

#ifndef DUMB_H
#define DUMB_H

class Dummy {
    int num_of_teeth;
public:
    Dummy(int num) {
        num_of_teeth = num;
    }
    ~Dummy() {};
    void add(int num) {
        num_of_teeth += num;
    }
    void remove() {
        num_of_teeth --;
    }
    void operator = (Dummy &dumb) {
        num_of_teeth = dumb.num_of_teeth;
    }
    bool operator < ( Dummy &dumb ) {
        return num_of_teeth < dumb.num_of_teeth ? true : false;
    }

    bool operator > ( Dummy &dumb ) {
        return num_of_teeth > dumb.num_of_teeth ? true : false;
    }

    bool operator == ( Dummy &dumb ) {
        if ( dumb.num_of_teeth == num_of_teeth ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    void print() {
        int num = num_of_teeth;
        while (num > 0) {
            cout << "D";
            if ((num-1) == (num_of_teeth/2)) {
                cout << "\n";
            }
            num --;
            if (num == 0) {
                cout << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Dummy& dumb)
    {
        output << dumb.num_of_teeth;
        return output;
    }
};

#endif
```

And when I try to compile it I get the Error:

```
   ====================[ Build | exe_name | Debug ]================================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.1.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\ex2.2\cmake-build-debug --target exe_name -- -j 3
Scanning dependencies of target exe_name
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/exe_name.dir/main.cpp.obj
In file included from C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\ex2.2\main.cpp:2:
C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\ex2.2\sortedList.h: In instantiation of 'LinkedList<T> LinkedList<T>::filter(LinkedList<T>&, B) [with B = bool (*)(int); T = Dummy]':
C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\ex2.2\main.cpp:36:45:   required from here
C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\ex2.2\sortedList.h:112:21: error: cannot convert 'Dummy' to 'int' in argument passing
             if (pred((curr -> data))) {
                 ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\exe_name.dir\build.make:81: CMakeFiles/exe_name.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: CMakeFiles/exe_name.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:101: CMakeFiles/exe_name.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:136: exe_name] Error 2
```

Where should I change the code to make it work? And how?

**edit:
After I changed the function in main to:

```
bool func(Dummy num) {
    int number = num.get();
    if (number % 2 != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It compiles but returns an unending list of unknown numbers..
like-

```
16740248
16711872
16740296
16740248
16711872
16740296
16740248
16711872
16740296
16740248
16711872
16740296
16740248
16711872

Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

Where in the code do I try to reach a forbidden memory? or a corrupted one?

Comment: Upvoted without even looking at the problem for showing the code *and* the error ;-).

Comment: please remove the comment blocks, they arent needed to reproduce the error, no?

Comment: I cannot find the code the compiler complains about in your code samples. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica ow sorry yeah I accidentally copied the error I got when I tried to fix it. Edited it now to the correct error.

Comment: How to make it work may be overambitious at this stage, let's focus on the error. It's saying that the second argument to filter should be some kind of function. From the logic of the thing, it should be a function that takes T and returns bool. What is it declared as? It is a value of an unrelated type B. This might work by accident if you feed it `a function that takes T and returns bool`. What are you feeding it? A function that takes int and returns bool. Nope, func should have a Dummy argument.

Comment: Your filter predicate function awaits an int, but your list contains Dummy-values.
`bool func(int num) {` should be `bool func(const Dummy& num) {`

Comment: You pass an entire Dummy to the predicate function. Presumably, you only want to pass the number of teeth?

Comment: @SimonKraemer I can't use Dummy because it's supposed to be generic, no?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica yes, how can I do that?

Comment: LinkedList is generic, if you are writing a predicate to use with a `LinkedList<Dummy>`, that predicate function will usually be non-generic and can use specifics of the Dummy type that LinkedList is not aware of.

Comment: @SimonKraemer when I try to use it with bool func(const Dummy& num) { I get the error error: no match for 'operator%' (operand types are 'const Dummy' and 'int')
     if (num % 2 != 0) {

Comment: `string& operator*()
        { return m_ptr->data(); }` This looks suspicious. `data` is of type `T`. It's not sure that it provides `operator()` nor whether it returns `string&`, does it?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat oh yeah I still have to work on that, not even trying to use the Iterator yet ><

Comment: The current edit seems to be missing an implementation of the `filter` function which makes the question a bit hard to understand.

Comment: @dratenik the main remained the same, only the bool func changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass an entire Dummy to the predicate function when you call `pred((curr -> data)`. `pred`, coming from the line  `dummy1 = dummy1.filter(teeth_list, &func);`, is a function expecting an int, which it doesn't get.

There are a couple of potential fixes.

1. Use a function that expects a Dummy (and extracts the teeth itself ;-) ).
2. Pass the number of teeth (which are currently inaccessible), not the entire Dummy.
3. Providing a conversion operator to `int` in `Dummy` (presumably returning the number of teeth) should work as well.

The conversion operator approach seemed to work for me. I inserted

```
    operator int() { return num_of_teeth; }
```

into the `Dummy` class in the public section.

Whether that is good style is debatable. It may be unexpected that a Dummy is also an int. There is perhaps also an argument that the predicate function should work on the entire node data, but that is debatable: A general, reusable function that can handle everything int-oid has its merits as well. Since C++11 you can mitigate the unexpectedness of a conversion to `int` by making it explicit: It is still possible but requires a static cast.

As for the rest of the code:

- Define a proper assignment for the list: `head = t.head;`— a shallow copy, sharing all nodes — leads to **double deletes on each node** when the lists go out of scope
- **Do not mix malloc and delete**
- Do not use naked pointers in the first place, use smart pointers
- Check your insert function, the logic seems overly complicated and may be buggy
- The Node constructor should also null `next`
- You'll likely need const iterators.

Make sure to write extensive tests for such a container class with wild inserts and deletes, at the beginning, the end etc. Make sure to cover all edge cases with empty lists. Containers are hard to get perfectly correct without rigorous tests.

Comment: I changed the function but now it returns some nonsense so I guess I have some memory issues.. Do you maybe see the problem?

Comment: It was in the errors as well... I didn't look into it but it seems you are returning a reference to a temporary somewhere.

Comment: @SpaceNugget are you going to keep changing the meaning of the question until you debug the whole thing? Do you require the accepted answer to address all the iterations of your question? (hint: for a different question, you're supposed to open a new one)

Comment: @dratenik The question seems to have been edited 25 minutes ago, fixing an editorial mistake. I think the OP is asking a simple favor here which he is welcome to do.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Thank you <3 I could create a new question about the memory problem but I thought that it relates to this one and if people in the future will try to use my code they would love to have the answer to that as well ><